# resultset.next taking long time

Tags: oracle, jdbc, plsql, oracle11g

I am using Oracle JDBC connection and executing procedure using CallableStatement.

```
procedureCall.executeUpdate(); // That took 149 milliseconds
resultSet.next() // That took 5287 milliseconds
```

Query execution time is ok. But when i do resultSet.next, it is taking long time.

Can Anyone please tell why such behavior is happening.

**EDIT**

```
try (CallableStatement procedureCall = connection.prepareCall(PROC_NAME)) {
procedureCall.setLong("param",value);
procedureCall.registerOutParameter("param1",OracleTypes.CURSOR)
procedureCall.registerOutParameter("param2",OracleTypes.CURSOR)
procedureCall.executeUpdate();
resultSet = (ResultSet) procedureCall.getObject("param1");
while(resultset.next()){
}
resultSet.close();
resultSet = (ResultSet) procedureCall.getObject("param2");
while(resultset.next()){
}
resultSet.close();
}catch(SQLException e){
}finally {
     if (resultSet != null) {
         try {
               resultSet.close();
             } catch (SQLException ex) { }
            }
        }
```

**Workaround**
Also tried `resultset.setFetchsize(2);` and `if(resultset.next()){}`
Still taking same time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are some other operations in your code between these two statements. Try to add log messages with time stamps. If the 5287 msec is measured just before and after the `resultset.next()` , then you should check the AWR report of Oracle, and see where the bottleneck is. Also, you can perform this operation in a loop, so that you generate a real load on the DB, which will be measurable in the AWR.

Comment: There isn't any operation in between.

Comment: How many records are updated in the executeUpdate() ? Could you please add some more code lines before and after these two?

Comment: Do you know how many records are updated, and how many iterations are done in the loop?

Comment: Hi Galcoholic. Eventhough i iterate it once the result is same.